# Ruby on rails installation fails on my mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

**Running:**

- Mac OS X Lion 10.7.4
- xCode Version 4.4.1
- Ruby 1.8.x
- Brew
- Rvm

I'm trying to install ruby on rails on my mac (above are my specs). But it doesn't really come out the way it used to be. I tried several tutorials on the web including Stack Overflow.

As soon as I try:

```
$ sudo gem install rails
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

Same with Ruby 1.9.2

**EDIT**
Error for installing ruby

```
Peter-Corverss-MacBook-Pro:~ Beer$ rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p290
Fetching yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/Beer/.rvm/archives
Extracting yaml-0.1.4.tar.gz to /Users/Beer/.rvm/src
Configuring yaml in /Users/Beer/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/Beer/.rvm/usr', please read /Users/Beer/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/yaml/configure.log
Compiling yaml in /Users/Beer/.rvm/src/yaml-0.1.4.
Error running 'make', please read /Users/Beer/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/yaml/make.log
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/Beer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #downloading ruby-1.9.2-p290, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 8604k  100 8604k    0     0   225k      0  0:00:38  0:00:38 --:--:--  202k
ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #extracting ruby-1.9.2-p290 to /Users/Beer/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290
ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #extracted to /Users/Beer/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290
ruby-1.9.2-p290 - #configuring 
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/Beer/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290 --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --with-libyaml --with-opt-dir=/Users/Beer/.rvm/usr', please read /Users/Beer/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p290/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Above code with some color (image):

[image]

This is the start for installing ruby and I can't get it to work.

I really tried but I can't fix the problem, hope someone could help me.

Comment: Can you post which gem it's failing to install, as rails is composed of many gems, so it must be a specific one that's having trouble building. You may need to open up xcode, go into the downloads and grab the command line utilities. I do recommend installing through ruby 1.9.x if you can as supposed to 1.8.

Comment: Thx for quick response! I edited the post with some more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah if you're having trouble building ruby, you probably need the command line utilities from Xcode. Checkout: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-documentation_preferences/DownloadingandInstallingXcodeComponents/DownloadingandInstallingXcodeComponents.html

It's in the preferences pane with a downloads tab.

After that installs, reopen terminal and try to install 1.9.2 through rvm again. If it doesnt install still, please comment and I'll see if I can figure it out. If it does install, try installing both rails & bundler:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.2 --default
gem install rails
gem install bundler
```

The first line will switch you into 1.9.2 and should set it up as your default environment.